# Trouble in 3DS MAX 2016 exported ogre.mesh file refering the correct .material

Tags: ogre, 3dsmax, mesh, materials

Actually we have some trouble in exporting ogre mesh + material files correctly from 3dsmax.
We are using "Easy Ogre Exporter V 2.40" for the export to ogre format.
And actually just testing its features by displaying the images in Cegui-Meshviewer
(http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=CEGUI+Mesh+Viewer).

The problem is, the mesh itself refers to a material file, which has added "default" on to it. So for example if we exported "stone.mesh" the exported material would be "stone.material" which is fine. But when inspecting the mesh inside any mesh viewing tool run on ogreengine, the mesh itself is related to a so called "stoneDefault.material" which if I want to get its attributes listed just has no attributes set. But when I inspect the material itself ("stone.material") In those mesh viewers, I can see the correct UV map related to the material and the other attributes fit to what is expected aswell. But the mesh it self seems to be using an non existing "stoneDefault.material" (thats at least the name related to it) And I also checked if it changes anythign when I just change the name of "stone.material" to "stoneDefault.material" But this jsut resaulted in 2 different materials with the same name isnide the viewer.

So my Question is: Is this probably a bug in the viiewers/exporter?
Or am I missing/missunderstanding soemthing?

we selected for testing portability ogre version 1 as exporting file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The export and Mesh were fine. It just figured out to be a bug in the meshviewer so we had to switch the tool we used. Now everything is working fine.